# binding to constant values in mvvm

Tags: mvvm, view, binding, constants

i have constant values (certain limits) i work with in the viewmodel but i need it in my view as well. what is the best way to do that?

constant:

```
private const int maxLevel = 4;
```

do i really need to make a property for each constant and bind to it like that:

```
private const int _maxLevel = 4;
public int MaxLevel
{
    get { return _maxLevel; }
    set
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("MaxLevel");
    }
}
```

maybe i could store all those values in a *.resx file like i do it with strings? what is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the setter. Property change notification is only needed to inform binding elements that the value has changed. Since MaxLevel is a constant its value never changes, thus you don't need it. You can't bind directly to a constant because in practice the compiler embeds the value into the code that accesses it at compile time, so for constant properties that are unlikely to need future modification I usually just do something like this:

```
public int MaxLevel { get {return 4;} }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
namespace Foo.ViewModels
{
  public class MainWindowViewModel{
    public const int MaxLevel = 4; 
    ...
  }
}
```

and use it in the view:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static Foo.ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel.MaxLevel}"></Label>
```

Or generally speaking, bind to:

```
"{x:Static MyNameSpace:MyClass.MY_CONSTANT}"
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will not work, e.g., with a TextBlock, because it expects a string but the constant is an integer.